# USB device location on windows XP

Tags: windows, usb, setupapi

I'm trying to group USB devices based on their parent hub by using the SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty function with the SPDRP_LOCATION_INFORMATION property.

On windows 7 it's working great - the string I'm getting is a nice "PORT_XXXX&HUB_XXXX". But when trying to do the same on Windows XP, I'm getting the device name instead.

Does anyone know what is going on? Is it a bug in Windows XP?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you resolved this problem with win xp?

Comment: No. We decided to drop support for XP.